# Simplify Google Sheets Sum Formula?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

This might be a super easy fix.

I'm just getting started with formulas and I want to simplify my document so it can run a little faster.

I have a big sum formula:

```
IF(D2<>"X - Done";C2;0)
```

and the same IF for the two following columns so

```
;IF(F2<>"X - Done";E2;0).
```

*ETC.*

Can someone help me simplify this please?

`=sum(IF(D47<>"X - Done";C47;0);IF(F47<>"X - Done";E47;0);IF(H47<>"X - Done";G47;0);IF(J47<>"X - Done";I47;0);IF(L47<>"X - Done";K47;0);IF(N47<>"X - Done";M47;0);IF(P47<>"X - Done";O47;0);IF(R47<>"X - Done";Q47;0);IF(T47<>"X - Done";S47;0);IF(V47<>"X - Done";U47;0);IF(X47<>"X - Done";W47;0);IF(Z47<>"X - Done";Y47;0);IF(AB47<>"X - Done";AA47;0);IF(AD47<>"X - Done";AC47;0);IF(AF47<>"X - Done";AE47;0);IF(AH47<>"X - Done";AG47;0);IF(AJ47<>"X - Done";AI47;0);IF(AL47<>"X - Done";AK47;0);IF(AN47<>"X - Done";AM47;0);IF(AP47<>"X - Done";AO47;0);IF(AR47<>"X - Done";AQ47;0);IF(AT47<>"X - Done";AS47;0);IF(AV47<>"X - Done";AU47;0);IF(AX47<>"X - Done";AW47;0);IF(AZ47<>"X - Done";AY47;0);IF(BB47<>"X - Done";BA47;0);IF(BD47<>"X - Done";BC47;0);IF(BF47<>"X - Done";BE47;0);IF(BH47<>"X - Done";BG47;0);IF(BJ47<>"X - Done";BI47;0);IF(BL47<>"X - Done";BK47;0);IF(BN47<>"X - Done";BM47;0);IF(BP47<>"X - Done";BO47;0);IF(BR47<>"X - Done";BQ47;0);IF(BT47<>"X - Done";BS47;0);IF(BV47<>"X - Done";BU47;0);IF(BX47<>"X - Done";BW47;0);IF(BZ47<>"X - Done";BY47;0);;IF(CB47<>"X - Done";CA47;0);IF(CD47<>"X - Done";CC47;0);IF(CF47<>"X - Done";CE47;0);IF(CH47<>"X - Done";CG47;0);IF(CJ47<>"X - Done";CI47;0);IF(CL47<>"X - Done";CK47;0);IF(CN47<>"X - Done";CM47;0);IF(CP47<>"X - Done";CO47;0);IF(CR47<>"X - Done";CQ47;0);IF(CT47<>"X - Done";CS47;0);IF(CV47<>"X - Done";CU47;0))`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your current formula appears to sum the values in cells in every odd-numbered column between `C:CV`, with the condition that the value in the cell immediately to the right of said value must equal "X - Done".

Try this shorter formula to accomplish the same:

`=sum( iferror( filter(C47:CU47; D47:CV47 <> "X - Done") ) )`

The `iferror()` guards against the event that no value in the range fulfills the "X - Done" criteria.

Comment: This answer was automatically marked as low quality. Please consider to add a brief description of how this formula answer the question or if the questions was already answered flag / vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Rubén.